# How to reference data with dynamic dates in excel?

Tags: excel, finance, modeling

I have a financial model in which Occupancy numbers vary depending on when the construction phase has been completed. I have another cash flow tab which should show in Year 1 occupancy numbers regardless of when they were completed in the other tab.

i.e. Occupancy Begins Month 10 in Development Tabs: 500 sqft. In Cash Flow Tab - Year 1/Month 1: sqft and so on.

Is there any clever way to do this in Excel?

Very much struggling

I tried using HLOOKUP but fall short with the dates end.

I have attached an example:

Please note the HLOOKUP references Table 1 Top Row '16' with the Table 2 16 - with the result just below Table 1. Basically I am trying to assume whenever Occupancy starts it translates into Month 1 in my table

[Example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ftJRF.png)

Comment: I'm struggling to understand the question and problem

Comment: You should show how your data looks like, as it's quite difficult to imagine the data structure otherwise. You should also show what you've tried so far

Comment: Sure thing - now updated!